# an alternative to nested for loops in r OR possible Rcpp needed?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rcpp

I have a nested loop as

```
X <- matrix(c(0.5,0,0,0.75), nrow = 2)
k = nrow(X)

ans1 <- 0
ans2 <- 0
for (aa in 1:k) {
  for (bb in 1:k) {
    for (cc in 1:k) {
      for (dd in 1:k) {
        ans1 = ans1 + (0.45 * X[aa,bb] * X[cc,dd])
        for (xx in 1:k) {
          for (yy in 1:k){ 
            ans2 = ans2 + (1.7*X[aa,bb]*X[xx,yy]*X[cc,dd] + 0.2*X[aa,xx]*X[bb,yy]*X[cc,dd])  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the matrix `X` which must be a square matrix can be of very high dimensions. Which would therefore slow the loop considerably. e.g. `X = matrix(rnorm(10000),nrow = 100,byrow = T)`

I am wondering if there is a shorter way to compress this. That would be readable and most importantly a slightly faster. I have tried `expand.grid` but this doesn't help much.

For instance for `ans1`

```
library(tidyverse)
an1 <- expand.grid(rep(list(seq(length(X))),2)) %>% arrange_all()
an11 <- t(apply(an1, 1, function(x) as.vector(t(X))[x]))
```

But as I mentioned, this doesn't improve the speed. Any suggestions? I am also thinking Rcpp might help but I am not sure and I have not tried that (not very good with the c++ syntax).

Comment: Try factoring out as much as possible. For example, X[aa,bb] can be removed from the cc and dd loops.

Comment: Isn't `ans1` equal to `0.45*sum(X)^2` and `ans2` equal to `1.9*sum(X)^3`?  Those will be pretty quick to evaluate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use loops at all.  Since your code for `ans1` and `ans2` is just a sum of terms, and those terms don't interact at all, the expressions simplify to

```
ans1simple <- 0.45*sum(X)^2
ans2simple <- 1.9*sum(X)^3
```

You can test this on random data.  Change the seed or size of `X` if you're not convinced:

```r
set.seed(123)

X <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3)
k = nrow(X)

ans1 <- 0
ans2 <- 0
for (aa in 1:k) {
  for (bb in 1:k) {
    for (cc in 1:k) {
      for (dd in 1:k) {
        ans1 = ans1 + (0.45 * X[aa,bb] * X[cc,dd])
        for (xx in 1:k) {
          for (yy in 1:k){ 
            ans2 = ans2 + (1.7*X[aa,bb]*X[xx,yy]*X[cc,dd] + 0.2*X[aa,xx]*X[bb,yy]*X[cc,dd])  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

ans1simple <- 0.45*sum(X)^2
ans2simple <- 1.9*sum(X)^3
ans1 - ans1simple
#> [1] 2.220446e-16
ans2 - ans2simple
#> [1] -7.993606e-15
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The differences are just rounding error.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops in R are very slow compared to `for` loops in C++.

C++ `for` loop syntax isn't too different from some flavors of R.

I highly suspect you can condense your code significantly. But just going by your very nested syntax:

**Rcpp function:**

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector foo(Rcpp::NumericMatrix& X) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector ans(2);
    int k = X.rows();
    for (int aa = 0; aa < k; ++aa) {
        for (int bb = 0; bb < k; ++bb) {
            for (int cc = 0; cc < k; ++cc) {
                for (int dd = 0; dd < k; ++dd) {
                    ans[0] += 0.45 * X[aa, bb] * X[cc, dd]l;
                    for (int xx = 0; xx < k; ++xx) {
                        for (int yy = 0; yy < k; ++yy) {
                            ans[1] += (1.7 * X[aa, bb] * X[xx, yy] * X[cc, dd] + 0.2 * X[aa, xx] * X[bb, yy] * X[cc, dd]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

**On the R end:**

```
X <- matrix(c(0.5,0,0,0.75), nrow = 2)
ans <- foo(X)
ans1 <- ans[1]
ans2 <- ans[2]
```

Plugging-and-chugging with the above code is NOT an excuse for not optimizing your code. Again, cut the number of loops. You shouldn't need them all.

---

After seeing @user2554330's answer (which I suspected was the case but was too lazy to work out), the Rcpp implementation will not be significantly faster than the R implementation (and I doubt you're worrying about such marginal gains)